# Leave a repository on bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

Last year, I was working with some other people on a computer science project. So, I created a bitbucket repository and invited everybody. As we know each other very well, everybody is an administrator of the repository and I'm the owner.

Today, I would like to clean up my bitbucket repository list. But, I can't find how to leave a repository. When I go in the settings menu, the only thing that I can do is "deleting a repository". It's not what I want to do because I want to leave the repository for the other people.

For some repository (when I'm not the owner), I can revoke myself, but for the other, I can't. Do you know how can I do that? I would like to find a solution without needing to make a ownership transfer as it involves making a transfer request and then, waiting some time to get the answer.

Thank you

Comment: @DanWhite, this _is_ [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): it is about "software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Answer (score 9):

1. Go to 'Your profile and Settings' left bottom corner &  Tap 'All work spaces'

[image]

2. Tap 'Leave'

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to find a solution without needing to make a ownership transfer as it involves making a transfer request and then, waiting some time to get the answer.

*Somebody* must own the repository, and you can't leave a repository that you own.

You could create a [team](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/bitbucket-cloud-teams-321853005.html) and transfer the repository there, then invite the other users to the team. Transferring your repo to a team you create should be instantaneous.

Or you can transfer the repository to an existing user and wait for them to respond, as you have suggested.

Comment: Not sure where the downvotes are coming from… If there is something wrong with my answer, please let me know?

Comment: I don't know for the downvotes. I'm OK that somebody must own the repository. So, there should be a way to quit my own directory and *automatically* transfer it to any other admin? Is it right?

Comment: @AlexisClarembeau, no, I don't think there's any way to automatically transfer a repository to another user. How would you like it if you woke up to a new repository in your Bitbucket? How about 10, or 100? I think your only options are to (a) delete it (which you don't want to do), (b) create a team and move it there (which I think is your best bet), or (c) transfer it to another user and wait for them to accept the transfer.

Comment: Is there a way to leave a team on Bitbucket without contacting the team or it s members where I am a member but not an admin?

Answer (score 1):

Workaround:

Disable "New source browser experience" in here: https://bitbucket.org/account/user//features/

Then click "revoke" in here: https://bitbucket.org///overview